# To check continuity and differentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function[image]

I am having problem with checking continuity because of y. Regarding differentiability i can apply Leibniz rule to get explicit formula.But then modulus part troubles me. Can somebody show me way to do this? Thanks

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I've noticed that you have asked quite a few questions recently. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^x \{5 + |1-y|\} dy = \int_0^1 \{5 + 1-y \} dy + \int_1^x \{5 + y-1 \} dy $$
$$=\int_0^1 \{6-y \} dy + \int_1^x \{4+y\} dy$$
$$=6-\frac{1}{2}+4(x-1)+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{2}+4x+1$$

So $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2}{2}+4x+1 & x > 2 \\ 5x+2 & x \le 2\end{cases}$$

Does this help?

Comment: @Arthur For $x \le 1$, $f(x)=5x+2$ as the question states. I didn't get you. Can you show me the mistake I have made?

Comment: @Arthur yes please explain

Comment: I misread the inequalities in the original question, thought the integral was for $x < 2$.

Answer (score 1):

OK, In fact, you should evaluate the integral first and it it will be easy to investigate the continuity and differentiability. So I just compute the integral for you

$$\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{x}(5+|1-y|) dy \\
&=  \int_{0}^{1}(5+|1-y|) dy + \int_{1}^{x}(5+|1-y|) dy & \text{This is true for all real numbers $x$}  \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}(6-y) dy + \int_{1}^{x}(4+y) dy & \text{Note that $x \gt 2$ and hence $|1-y|=-(1-y)$} \\
&= \left( 6y- \frac{y^2}{2}\right)_{0}^{1} +\left( 4y+ \frac{y^2}{2}\right)_{1}^{x} \\
&= \left(\frac{11}{2}-0\right) + \left(4x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{9}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{x^2}{2} + 4x +1
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you explain Arthur's comment in above answer

Comment: @SophieClad: I think that he didn't notice $x \gt 2$! :) It is all about deciding on the sign of $|1-y|$ in the integrand. :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely $f $ is not continuous at $x=2$:

$f(2+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\int _0^{2+h}5+|1-y|\operatorname{dy}=\lim_{h\to 0}\int _0^25+|1-y|\operatorname{dy}=10 $ which is true both for $y<1$ or $y>1$.

Obviously $f(2-h)=12$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\int_0^x(5+|1-y|)dy \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  if \ x>2$$
Differentiating w.r.t. "x" we get
$$f'(X)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x(5+|1-y|)dy$$
$$f'(X)=5+|1-x|$$
As $x>2$ then $x-1>1$
$$f'(X)=5+(x-1)$$
$$f'(X)=4+x$$
Integrating w.r.t. "x"
$$f(x)=4x+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
By the definition of continuity we can find the value of $c=2$ so that
$$f(x)=4x+\frac{x^2}{2}+2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ if \ x>2$$